# How to exclude some records in string in kdb?

Tags: kdb

I would like to exclude some records from the table.

```
a:("abc*";"eeee*")
tab:([]cola:("abcdef";"bcdefgh";"tttttt");colb:`a`b`c)
```

it works if I would like only certain records:
eg.

```
raze {select from tab where cola like x } each a
```

output:

```
cola     colb
-------------
"abcdef" a
```

Now I want to exclude the record above  by running the following command

```
raze {select from tab where not cola like x } each a
```

But it returns

```
cola      colb
--------------
"bcdefgh" b
"tttttt"  c
"abcdef"  a
"bcdefgh" b
"tttttt"  c
```

I would like it to return this:

```
 cola      colb
--------------
"bcdefgh" b
"tttttt"  c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
q)select from tab where not any cola like/: a
cola      colb
--------------
"bcdefgh" b   
"tttttt"  c
```

Edit: Why do we need an any?

If you index into the table with the column name to get the column as an array, it's easier to see:

```
q)tab[`cola]
"abcdef"
"bcdefgh"
"tttttt"
q)tab[`cola] like/: a
100b
000b
q)any tab[`cola] like/: a
100b
q)not any tab[`cola] like/: a
011b
```

When you use `like` with multiple strings and multiple regexes, you will get an array for each string (with the size of the array being the number of regexes). We want to see if our string matches any of the regexes, and then exclude them if they do.

Comment: it works. thank you! is it possible that you can explain a bit why you used any each

Comment: I changed tha table a bit cuz I got the length error.

Comment: I made another erorr now that I noticed you changed the table!